# Passing an environment variable (parameter) to dependency project in TeamCity

Tags: continuous-integration, environment-variables, teamcity

I have a build chain with two projects: A is the root project, B depends on it. B has two dependencies configured: an artifact and a snapshot dependency. One build configuration for B has an environment variable (parameter) set. However, I also need this parameter set for the root project A.

Is there any way in TeamCity 9 to pass a build configuration parameter from a project to its dependency (in the same build chain)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since TeamCity 9.0 it is possible to [override the dependencies parameters](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Predefined+Build+Parameters#PredefinedBuildParameters-OverridingDependenciesProperties) by redefining them in the dependent build:

```
reverse.dep.<btID>.<property name>
```

Comment: woa - didn't know this - good catch. This is what you want @Matthias

Comment: E.g. to pass an environment variable `env.myvariable` to the dependent snapshot: In the root configuration create a configuration variable called: `reverse.dep.*.env.myvariable`  (optionally replace wildcard with specific build id)

Comment: One gotcha is to make sure you don't have the desired variable set on the dependency. ie, if you have reverse.dep.*.env.myvariable in the root (which in my case is a release build), make sure you don't have env.myvariable set in the dependency (a unit test build in my case).

Comment: Any luck using this to update the branch being built from in a snapshot dependency? Here's my situation: A depends on B (snapshot dependency) which depends on C (snapshot & artifact dependency). When I run A, the branch being selected in B & C's VCS root needs to be changed. I've tried adding a `reverse.dep` in the dependent configuration (A) of the form `reverse.dep.<buildConfigID_B>.teamcity.build.vcs.branch.<vcsrootname>` but this did not work for me. The dependencies still get triggered with the default branch of their attached VCS root.

Comment: I managed to find a fix for the issue I've mentioned above: instead of using `reverse.dep.<buildConfigID_B>.teamcity.build.vcs.branch.<vcsrootname>`, I used `reverse.dep.<buildConfigID_B>.teamcity.build.branch`. This worked as expected - even though the build configuration of B has two VCS roots attached! I'm still wondering why the first way, which seems more unambiguous, does not work. Anybody know why?

Answer (score 5):

For TeamCity 8 and below unfortunately the only way parameters can be passed on is in the direction of the build chain - the reverse of what you want - these properties are called [Dependencies Properties](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Predefined+Build+Parameters#PredefinedBuildParameters-DependenciesProperties):

> **Dependencies Properties**
>
> These are properties provided by the builds the current build depends
>   on (via a snapshot or an artifact dependency).
>
> Dependencies properties have the following format:
>
> `dep.<btID>.<property name>`

Dependencies properties flow from the root of the tree to its leaves (in the direction of the build chain flow) , but not the other way round, so the properties of A can be accessed in B.

This is clarified in the docs [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Build+Dependencies+Setup#BuildDependenciesSetup-Reusingbuilds):

> **Parameters in dependent builds**
>
> TeamCity provides the ability to use properties provided by the builds
>   the current build depends on (via a snapshot or artifact dependency).
>   When build A depends on build B, you can pass properties from build B
>   to build A, i.e. properties can be passed only in the direction of the
>   build chain flow and not vice versa. For the details on how to use
>   parameters of the previous build in chain, refer to the Dependencies
>   Properties page.

I've had a similar use case for the reverse flow before as well - the workaround was not pretty - basically instead of triggering the build chain directly we would trigger an independent build (let's call it X) that was only there to hold the build parameters - then modify the build chain to have the root build (A in your case) depend on the last successful build of X and have the build chain trigger on a successful build of X - this should accomplish what you want.

**For TeamCity 9 see @Alina's answer** (which should be the accepted answer).

Comment: Well, I guess you're right, the docs confirm that this only works in the direction of the build chain. So I ended up with copying A's build configuration into another one, setting the variable there, and use it as dependency for B.