# Pass branch name to Snapshot Dependency in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity

I have 2 repos, A and B, which both have a build configuration in TeamCity.
Changes in repo A can impact repo B. When a PR is tested on repo A (say branch R), **I want to be able to start another teamcity job that tests repo B and will know about branch R**. More specifically, A runs on R, B runs on Master, B has a build step that requires R as an argument for a command. In teamcity, the build config for B is a snapshot dependency for the build config of A.

This other answer showed me how to pass parameters to snapshot dependencies: [Passing an environment variable (parameter) to dependency project in TeamCity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28822099/passing-an-environment-variable-parameter-to-dependency-project-in-teamcity)
However, I can't pass the branch name like %teamcity.build.branch% because the documentation specifies:

> Note that the values of the reverse.dep. parameters are pushed to the
>   dependency builds "as is", without reference resolution. %-references,
>   if any, will be resolved in the context of the build where the
>   parameters are pushed to.

from:
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Predefined+Build+Parameters#PredefinedBuildParameters-OverridingDependenciesProperties

Answer (score 0):

You can use a finish build trigger for B and make sure the trigger can use the same branch R.

Wait for a successful build in: A
Branch filter:
+:R

Comment: The two repos will run on different branches. I added this edit to my question to clarify: "More specifically, A runs on R, B runs on Master, B has a build step that requires R as an argument for a command"

Comment: Since you B has a snapshot depedencey on A, you can use the following in the step that needs the branch name from A

%dep.TestProjects_A.teamcity.build.branch%

Comment: Negative, it is A that needs the branch name from B. B can access A's branch with %dep, but not the other way around.